# git push changes to other branch after set of changes are made

Tags: git, git-push

I currently have an application on "master" and I used a tested script which generates my documentation.

However, I would like to push the changes to my application done after this script has run on a separate branch named "stable".

I tried to create my branch then do a `git checkout stable` and `git pull origin master`.

But the changes do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

With `master` checked out (and up to date), you can create a branch from it using:

```
git checkout -b Stable
```

You will now be on a branch called `Stable` which will be equivalent to your `master` branch. Commit your changes (i.e. your documentation) to this branch, then push and you will have what you want.

Comment: I have already create my branch in github, -b will just create again no ?

Comment: Yes it will. If you don't need anything from that branch, just delete it and start again (`git branch -D Stable`).